# How to sum values in dictionary with multiple elements in string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to sum values in a dictionary that has strings for keys, and lists as the values.

The standard `sum(d.values())` doesn't work.

```
d= {'a': [6,7,8], 'b':[30,-3, 5000,] 'c':[200.6], 'd':[2,2,2,2,2,2,2]}
```

When I use the `sum(d.values())` I get:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Comment: Are you looking to sum the lists for each key, or the total for the dictionary?

Comment: Just the total for the dictionary not for each key.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sum` and `map` on the `dicts's values` like this

```
>>> sum(map(sum, d.values()))
5262.6
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to create a generator that takes the sum of each array, and fianlly finds the sum of the values in the generator.

or if you just want to see the code.

`sum(sum(a) for a in d.values())`

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack the list of lists returned by `d.values()` as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists).

```py
sum(y for x in d.values() for y in x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `sum()` of the `sum()` of each sublist:

```
sum(sum(x) for x in d.values())
```

Or if you don't mind importing a library:

```
import itertools as it
sum(it.chain(*d.values()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Good solutions already here, but this is another way

```
sum(sum(a) for a in d.values())
```

Comment: Or `sum(sum(a) for a in d.values())` which I like so much I changed the answer. Thanks for triggering the memory.

Answer (score 1):

One version with `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

d= {'a': [6,7,8], 'b':[30,-3, 5000], 'c':[200.6], 'd':[2,2,2,2,2,2,2]}

print(sum(chain(*d.values())))
```

Prints:

```
5262.6
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the shortest way:-

```
sum( sum(d.values(), [] ) )
```

**Output**

```
5262.6
```